# 'Develop on Kubernetes stopped working since Intellij Update'

Tags: intellij-idea, kubernetes, google-cloud-code

This has been happening ever since I have updated Intellij (IDEA CE 2020.3) to a newer version (today). I am getting this exception from the plugin when running the `Develop on Kubernetes` Run Configuration that I usually use with my local Minikube instance to get all of the services in the cluster up and running, and able to Debug in debug mode.

My local Minikube instance is fine shown by the following:

```
(Dev) $ minikube status

minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

I've tried checking for updates, restarting Intellij, and I am still getting the same thing. It must be something in relation to my Intellij Update but we'll have to see...

The full stack trace is:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider not a subtype
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1236)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at io.grpc.ServiceProviders.loadAll(ServiceProviders.java:67)
    at io.grpc.ServiceProviders.load(ServiceProviders.java:42)
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider.<clinit>(ManagedChannelProvider.java:37)
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:37)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.intellij.kubernetes.skaffold.events.SkaffoldEventHandler.newManagedChannel(SkaffoldEventHandler.kt:319)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.intellij.kubernetes.skaffold.events.SkaffoldEventHandler.listenEvents(SkaffoldEventHandler.kt:75)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.intellij.kubernetes.skaffold.run.SkaffoldCommandLineState$startProcess$1.invokeSuspend(SkaffoldCommandLineState.kt:189)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
```

I am getting the same behaviour in both `DEBUG` mode and `RUN` mode.

#### Environment Info

- IDE type: IntelliJ
- IDE version: Community Edition 2020.3
- Cloud Code version:  20.10.1-202
- Skaffold version: v1.14.0
- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Any help, suggestions or resolutions would be really appreciated so thank you in advance! Thanks

Comment: Hi there. This issue was fixed with patch release 20.12.1 that was put out shortly after the EAP release. Please try it out and if you run into any other issues feel free to post on our GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry I posted the issue, and patches just recently got pushed because the new 2020.3 created dependency issues within the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed with patch release 20.12.1 that was put out shortly after the EAP release. Please try it out and if you run into any other issues feel free to post on our GitHub. – eshaul